# pl/sql PLS-00201 identifier must be declared

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

Newbie to PL/SQL. I have several questions, so here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "my_procedure" (
   "my_inparam1"              IN     VARCHAR2,
   "my_inparam2"              IN     VARCHAR2,
   "my_output"                OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
   sql_text   VARCHAR2 (10000);
BEGIN
    sql_text :=
      'select something
       from my_table
       where 1 = 1';

   IF '&my_inparam1' <> 'foo'
   THEN
      sql_text := sql_text || ' and something = 0';
   END IF;

   IF '&my_inparam1' = 'foo' and '&my_inparam2' = 'bar'
   THEN
      sql_text := sql_text || ' and somethingelse = 1';
   ELSIF '&my_inparam1' = 'foo' AND '&my_inparam2' = 'baz'
   THEN
      sql_text := sql_text || ' and somethingelse = 0';
   END IF;

   OPEN my_output FOR sql_text; --ERROR PLS-00201 Identifier 'MY_OUTPUT' must be declared
END;
```

So obviously I'm trying to return a query result, optionally filtered by whatever parameters I pass in. I'm at a loss as to why the offending line returns an error - in an earlier iteration, I was able to return results, but now, mysteriously, it's stopped working.

1) Is there a better way to approach this?

2) Do I have to reference the input params with the '&my_inparam' syntax?

3) If I do approach this by creating the sql text first and then opening the ref cursor, is there a shortcut for concatening the strings, like

```
sql_text &= ' and another_condition = 1'
```

?

Comment: FWIW - double-quotes around a variable name (or just about anything in Oracle) make that name "CaSe SenSiTivE", Default capitalization in Oracle is UPPER_CASE, but if you don't double-quote it you can enter it as upper_case, Upper_Case, uPpEr_CaSe, or however you like and the database system will convert it to upper case for you. IMO a good rule to follow is: never, ever, EVER double-quote ANY IDENTIFIER in Oracle. :-) ShArE aNd EnJoY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In reverse order... no, there is no shorthand for concatenation like `&=`. You could use the `concat()` function instead, but the `||` method is more common, and more convenient especially if you're sticking more than two things together - nested `concat()` calls aren't as easy to follow. I'd stick with what you're doing.

Secondly, no, you're confusing SQL*Plus substitution variables with PL/SQL variables. Your references to `'&my_inparam1'` should be `my_inparam1`, etc; no ampersand and no quotes.

Except for some reason you've decided to make life difficult for yourself and use case-sentisive procedure and variable names, so you have to refer to `"my_inparam1"`, in double quotes, *everywhere*.

That's why you're getting the message `PLS-00201 Identifier 'MY_OUTPUT' must be declared`. You didn't quote `my_output` so by default it's looking for a case-insensitive variable called `MY_OUTPUT`, which does not exist. It would work if you did this instead:

```
OPEN "my_output" FOR sql_text;
```

Unless you have a really really good reason, really don't do that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure (
   my_inparam1              IN     VARCHAR2,
   my_inparam2              IN     VARCHAR2,
   my_output                OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
   sql_text   VARCHAR2 (10000);
BEGIN
    sql_text :=
      'select something
       from my_table
       where 1 = 1';

   IF my_inparam1 <> 'foo'
   THEN
      sql_text := sql_text || ' and something = 0';
   END IF;
...
   OPEN my_output FOR sql_text;
END;
```

For more information, refer to the [naming rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm):

> Every database object has a name. In a SQL statement, you represent
>   the name of an object with a quoted identifier or a nonquoted
>   identifier.
>
> A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks (").
>   If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then you must
>   use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.
>
> A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

And more importantly:

> **Note:**
>   Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names. These quoted identifiers are accepted by
>   SQL*Plus, but they may not be valid when using other tools that manage
>   database objects.

You quoted procedure name falls into this category; so do the quoted variable names. They're all identifiers and the same advice applies.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yeah, I found out by experimentation that a) the double quotes on the output param fixed me error and b) that I didn't need to use the the double quotes on the input params either. The rest of my problems were simple syntax errors.